# Getting different hex value

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one device which gives data in non printable characters through serial port. I am converting the data to Hex by using Encoding(to get byte array of data) and then BitConverter.ToString()(to get the Hex String). But I am getting different hex value for the same data in Real Term(TCP Terminal). I need the value which is coming in Real Term. How do I do?
Ex: Data - "\t\0î\0\0\u0098$VeW",
My hex- 0900EE00003F24566557,
In Real Term - 0900EE00009824566557.
I have tried all types of Encoding.
Code:-

```
public void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10);
    string recievedData = port.ReadExisting();
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you should be reading the data as binary from the serial port to start with. Which API are you using, and are you sure it doesn't have a way of just reading the raw bytes?

Comment: I am receiving data through DataReceived event of Serial Port where I get the data as string.

Comment: Please show the code - the `DataReceived` event doesn't seem to actually give you the string itself. Anything stopping you from using the `Read(byte[], int, int)` method? If you'd include your code in the question, it would be easier to help you...

Comment: Right. Don't call `ReadExisting` - call the `Read` method that accepts a byte array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to read binary data as if it's text. Don't use the `ReadExisting()` call - use `Read(byte[], int, int)`:

```
public void HandleDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{        
    byte[] data = new byte[port.BytesToRead];
    int bytesRead = port.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    if (bytesRead != data.Length)
    {
        throw new IOException("Unable to read advertised number of bytes");
    }
}
```